# Ghost - how can I get related posts

Tags: ghost-blog, ghost

I'm using Ghost as blogging platform. When a user is reading a post I would like to show related posts in a sidebar.

I tried to use the ghost API but I cannot retrieve posts with a given tag and, in general, the post object doesn't contain the tag list.

I've found even a solution based on LinkWithin but, onestly, I really don't like the approach described here: http://pointblankpro.com/how-add-related-post-after-each-post-your-ghost/

Is there a way to get related posts based on the current post tags?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this code to work in displaying related posts in ghost: https://github.com/ljl/jquery.ghostrelated.

Also had a go at creating my own related post section using the API, but couldn't figure out how to pull in the current posts tag.

Comment: you may try to use guid i think from the feed